# How to check props with Flow in functional component so I can use props variables directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

I want to use props as variables directly without adding `props` object ahead of them.

Smth like: `onChange={handleChange}`, not `onChange={props.handleChange}`

```
   type Props = {
        handleChange: Function,
        values: Object,
        t: Function
    }
    
    function RadioList(props: Props) {
        return (
            <div className={css.radioList}>
                <RadioField
                    isFormik
                    name="some_name"
                    label={t('some_label')}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className={css.listFilterRadio}
                />
            </div>);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  type Props = {
        handleChange: Function,
        values: Object,
        t: Function
    }
    
    function RadioList(props: Props) {
        const { handleChange } = props; //  destructuring the props
        const { radioList, listFilterRadio } = css; // you can destrcture your css varible too if you are getting it from somewhere
        return (
            <div className={radioList}>
                <RadioField
                    isFormik
                    name="some_name"
                    label={t('some_label')}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className={listFilterRadio}
                />
            </div>);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
    function RadioList({handleChange}) {
    return (
        <div className={css.radioList}>
            <RadioField
                isFormik
                name="some_name"
                label={t('some_label')}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className={css.listFilterRadio}
            />
        </div>);
}
```